# Update the values in the DF based on the column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have next pandas DataFrame:

```
    x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 col_to_replace cor_factor
    
    1   2   3   4   x_2            1
    3   3   5   1   x_1            6
    2   2   0   0   x_3            0
...
```

I want to update the column which name is saved in the `col_to_replace` with the value from `cor_factor` and save the result in the corresponded column and also in the `car_factor` column.
Some (ugly) solution could be:

```
for i in len(df.shape[0]):
    df[df['col_to_replace']].iloc[i] = df[df['col_to_replace']].iloc[i] - df['cor_factor'].iloc[i]                                                                          
    df['cor_factor'].iloc[i] = df['cor_factor'].iloc[i] -  df[df['col_to_replace']].iloc[i]
```

This way is absolutely not time efficient. I'm looking for the faster solution.

The output for the DF should be in this case:

```
    x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 col_to_replace cor_factor
    
    1   1   3   4   x_2            -1
    -3  3   5   1   x_1            3
    2   2   0   0   x_3            0
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to correct the `x_` values and an [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) to correct the last column. Make sure to make a copy before modification since the values change:

```
# perform indexing lookup
# save the value for later
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['col_to_replace'])
corr = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]

# pivot and subtract the factor
# ensure original order of the columns
cols = df.columns.intersection(cols, sort=False)
df[cols] = df[cols].sub(df.pivot(columns='col_to_replace',
                                 values='cor_factor'),
                        fill_value=0).convert_dtypes()
# correct with the saved "corr"
df['cor_factor'] -= corr
```

Output:

```
   x_1  x_2  x_3  x_4 col_to_replace  cor_factor
0    1    1    3    4            x_2          -1
1   -3    3    5    1            x_1           3
2    2    2    0    0            x_3           0
```

Comment: @Timeless but it's a loop like OP's original approach, and they're "*looking for the faster solution.*" ;)

Answer (score 1):

One option is with numpy - np.diagonal and np.fill_diagonal. This feed off the idea that the positions are clear and there are no duplicates in `col_to_replace`

```py
# df = pd.read_clipboard()
A = df.copy()
others = A.loc[:, A.col_to_replace]
# work on a copy
values = np.diagonal(A.loc[:, A.col_to_replace]) 
np.fill_diagonal(others.to_numpy(), values - A.cor_factor)
A['cor_factor'] -= values
A = A.assign(**others)
A
   x_1  x_2  x_3  x_4 col_to_replace  cor_factor
0    1    1    3    4            x_2          -1
1   -3    3    5    1            x_1           3
2    2    2    0    0            x_3           0
```